# Python REST API flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests

I have a script which accepts arguments as JSON and gets executed. However I need to call the script through FLASK from a third party application POST method.

My Script is as below

```
import argparse
import os
import win32security, win32con
import ntsecuritycon as con
import pywintypes
import json
import sys, json

# Set up the argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('JSON', metavar='json',type=str, help='JSON to parse')

args = parser.parse_args()

# Get JSON data
json_str = args.JSON

# Parse JSON data
json_data = json.loads(json_str)

path = os.path.join(json_data["parentdir"], json_data["dirname"])
#print(json_data["parentdir"])
#print(json_data["dirname"])
os.mkdir(path)
```

The above scripts works when i run

```
python test.py "{\"parentdir\": \"D:\\Important\", \"dirname\": \"test\"}"
```

How I can call the same script as HTTP POST from a 3rd party API through flask. I have got idea on creating flask script but not sure how to pass the parameters to the script through flask route api

I tried below :
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

```
def hello_world():
    #parentdir = request.values.get("parentdir")
    #dirname = request.values.get("dirname")
    #print(dirname)
    #print(parentdir)
    parentdir = request.get_json("parentdir")
    dirname = request.get_json("dirname")
    path = os.path.join(parentdir, dirname)
    os.mkdir(path)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True) 

Error - Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked out the Python's Requests library? When you have your flask setup, you can use the Request library to do a POST to the path you specified on Flask with a JSON. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a flask route witch receives `parentdir` and `dirname` as parameters.
The route can execute the part of your script that create the dir.

```
import locale
import os

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

# Create Flask APP
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
    parentdir = request.json.get("parentdir")
    dirname = request.json.get("dirname")
    
    path = os.path.join(parentdir, dirname)
    # makedirs create directory recursively 
    os.makedirs(path)

    return jsonify()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, host="0.0.0.0", use_reloader=True)
```

The postman request

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "parentdir": "okn",
    "dirname": "okn"
}'
```